# Using this-as with enfocus's listen-live

Tags: clojurescript

I'm having issue using `this-as` with enfocus's `listen-live`. I'm using `listen-live` instead of `listen` because I am generating the `button` elements using javascript.

In the following minimum working code, there is a `HTML` file `/path/to/file.html` using `test.js` generated from clojurescript. When clicking the button I expected the console to log the `button` element but instead I receive `Window -> /path/to/file.html`.

`file.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="outer">
      <button>Button</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`file.cljs`:

```
(ns my.ns
  (:require [enfocus.events :as events])
  (:require-macros [enfocus.macros :as em]))

(em/defaction setup []
  [:.outer] (events/listen-live :click "button"
                                (fn [] (this-as this (js/console.log this)))))

(set! (.-onload js/window) setup)
```

I'm not overly familiar with javascript but I expected either the `button` or `.outer` element to be logged. Receiving the `Window` element makes me wonder if I have some fundamental usage issue or if it's an issue with`enfocus`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not ideal or idiomatic but the following works for me:

```
(em/defaction setup []
  [:.outer] (events/listen-live :click "button"
                                (fn [e] (js/console.log (.-currentTarget e)))))

=> <button>
```